# Can the following code be changed to be faster

Tags: python-3.x, lxml, elementtree

I have the following code and when I run it there is a long pause followed by a bunch of lines being printed after being parsed and then the process repeats. So I was wondering why there is a pause and how I can recode it to be more efficient in terms of memory and speed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from lxml import etree

subdirectories = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/dev/shm/heatmap/OpenHPC"):
    for i in dirs:
        if "compute" in i:
            subdirectories.append(i)

#for i in subdirectories:
#    os.system("cd /dev/shm/heatmap/OpenHPC/" + i + " && rrdtool dump cpu_temp.rrd cpu_temp.xml")

for i in subdirectories:
    with open(i+"/cpu_temp.xml") as f:
        doc = etree.parse(f)
    it = iter(doc.xpath(
        '//comment()[following-sibling::row] | //row/v/text()'
    ))
    for db_date, db_value in zip(it, it):
        with open("temperatureData.txt", 'a+') as f:
            f.write(i + " " + db_date.text.strip()[0:23] + " " +  db_value + "\n")
            print(f.write(i + " " + db_date.text.strip()[0:23] + " " +  db_value + "\n")
```

Comment: Off the bat, you'd probably only want to open "temperatureData.txt" once per subdirectory and then write the values in that context. Additionally, you'd want to minimize writes to that file, so joining all of those writes to that file with newlines and writing them once would save time too.

Comment: Could you post an example code? I understand opening "temperatureData.txt" once per subdirectory, but when you talk about minimizing writes is unclear.

Comment: Just posted an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File operations are expensive, the less often you have to do them the better. I suggest opening the file once for appending and minimizing writes. It depends on how much memory you have at your disposal but if you have a sufficient amount I suggest building an array of entries and batch writing them to file one time (some variables renamed for clarity):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from lxml import etree

subdirectories = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/dev/shm/heatmap/OpenHPC"):
    for subdir in dirs:
        if "compute" in subdir:
            subdirectories.append(subdir)

with open('temperatureData.txt', 'a+') as temperatureData:
    datalines = []
    for subdir in subdirectories:
        with open(subdir+"/cpu_temp.xml") as f:
            doc = etree.parse(f)
        it = iter(doc.xpath(
            '//comment()[following-sibling::row] | //row/v/text()'
        ))
        for db_date, db_value in zip(it, it):
            dataline = subdir + " " + db_data.text.strip()[0:23] + " " + db_value
            datalines.append(dataline)
            print(dataline)
    temperatureData.write('\n'.join(datalines))
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help